# Script to Recognize HDDs and run Smartctl

Tags: shell-script, hard-disk, smartctl

I'm thinking to do a script to recognize which HDDs are in use (sda, sdb, etc) and run a Smartctl on each one that's are in use, but I don't know how can I start, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
lsblk -o tran,name,mountpoint

lsblk --help

findmnt --help
```

So apparently some of the options I specified above are not yet too widely available. Ok. Try something like this:

```
for blk in $(lsblk -ndo name) ; do
    udevadm info --name /dev/$blk 
done
```

That should provide you all of the info you could need about the block devices on your system right now served up in handy little key=value pairs.

Comment: What's `tran`? I don't seem to have that column.

Comment: That's `transport` - like `sata` or `usb` - it's probably one you don't need for this particular problem. Consider updating though? Anyway, the old mtab/mount grepping solutions are being deprecated, or so my man page tells me. Findmnt is where it's at, which is not to mention lsblk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BASH scripting. Here is an example for what you can do **assuming you're in a linux OS** :

```
#!/bin/bash
mount | grep "/dev/sd" | awk '{print $1}' | while read partition
do 
    echo ${partition:0:8} 
done | sort | uniq | while read disk
do
    #All sdX disks are parsed here using the $disk variable
    echo "Disk : $disk"
    #Insert your smartctl commands here e.g:
    sudo smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on $disk
done
```

you can change the **/dev/sd** string above with the corresponding descriptor of your disks : **/dev/hd**, **/dev/sg** or whatever you find in your `mount` command output.

Comment: Disk's aren't always mounted via the device name, or necessarily named `sd` either.

Comment: @mindthemonkey, you're right i forgot about that. I've just edited the answer to mention it.